# Advanced Wordpress Post Relationships

Tags: php, wordpress, relationships, advanced-custom-fields, bidirectional

I am building a website for my theatre company.  I want it to contain complex, but easy to manage relationships throughout the site all relating to Shows and Artists and Reviews but I want all of the links to be bidirectional...so if I an actor to a show, the show automatically gets added under the actors profile as well.  Here is an example of the kinds of relationships I am trying to build through custom post types.

The main post type is **Shows**. Each show will contain **Artists**.  Each show will also contain **Articles and Reviews** relating to the show as well as show **Locations**.

All of the bolded items are custom post types I will be linking to shows via the Posts 2 Posts plugin and making bidirectional.  I know this sounds like a normal post relationship Movie type database (a la IMDB) and I am fairly comfortable up to this point...but here is where I get confused:

I want each **Show** to contain a list of Roles an **Artist** can play and assign an artist not only to the show, but to a particular role in that show and I want to do this in the most efficient manner possible.  Previously, I was using ACF to do something like this:

[Artist Role example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obJKD.png)

The problem with this is two-fold:

1. I have to use the ACF relationship field to connect the post types instead of Posts 2 Posts plugin...which means bidirectional linking will now become a big hassle.
2. This seems INCREDIBLY inefficient, as I am now running a query for the repeater field...then for EACH repeater field...I would have to run another query for the artist and artist info.  In a cast and crew of even just 10 people...that is a lot of queries for very little information.

I contemplated creating another post type called **Roles** and linking roles to **artists** and then querying the artists and the roles linked to them on the **show** page to display both, but again...I feel like this is inefficient and also means, since there are between maybe 4 - 8 roles in our shows, that the **roles** post type could quickly get huge and unwieldy in 3 - 4 seasons.

I should also note that each show will contain Actors, Designers, and a Directors (taxonomies of **Artists**)...each with their own roles that need to be associated with them.  See the below screenshot for the full functionality I am using to implement this currently with ACF.

[Full Artist Display ACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQLw6.png)

Comment: This may not be the best solution, but in the past, when I've had to create bi-directional relationships between posts, I've ended up making one of the posts a taxonomy. So if I had an Office Locations, Staff, and Projects setup, I had to make the locations a taxonomy, staff and projects 2 different post types, and go into each and assign the location to it. I then made the location archive page not return the staff or projects at all, and just use custom fields on the term to make a "page" for that office location. A similar approach MIGHT work for this.

Comment: Role should be a taxonomy or post meta field. OR don't worry about too many queries and add some full page caching.